# Get position of Focused item in ListView

Tags: c#, forms, listview, indexing, focus

In a **ListView** I want to get an int position ID of the item that is focused. Meaning the last selected item.

For example: If I click on item 10, the ID should become 10, but if I then hold CTRL and click on item 20 (then both 10 and 20 will be selected), then I want the ID to become 20.

This is what I've been trying, but it gives error when I'm selecting more than one item:

```
private void listSub_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  if (listSub.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(listSub.FocusedItem.Index + 1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want index, then you could get it by,

```
listSub.SelectedIndices[0];
```

**Edited:** If you have enabled Multiselect then you will iterate through the SelectedIndices array to get them all.

**Edit 2:** ItemSelectionChanged Listener, this is working for me...

```
        void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.IsSelected)
                MessageBox.Show(e.ItemIndex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I know, but then I only get the ID with the lowest number, not the item I clicked last.

Comment: Well, then take the value on upper bound.. listSub.SelectedIndices[listSub.SelectedIndices.Count-1];

Comment: That seems to always choose the highest positions.

Comment: Then use the ItemSelectionChanged listener instead. I will post a code snippet shortly.

Comment: This would work... the handler is fired once per added/removed selection though

Comment: That is why you would check if "e.IsSelected"

Comment: No. Only once per click... I just checked

Comment: Not for me... did you try to select 3 items at once?

Comment: No. OK, so you are trying to drag and select multiple items on a single click!!

Comment: It's no biggy and a safe solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you the last item clicked... you need add an evaluation whether its selected or not, but heres what i did in a MouseDown handler:

```
private void listSub_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lastClicked = listSub.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().SingleOrDefault(item => item.Bounds.Contains(e.X, e.Y));
    if (lastClicked != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lastClicked.Index.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Without Linq:

```
private void listSub_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in listSub.Items)
    {
        if (listViewItem.Bounds.Contains(e.X,e.Y))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(listViewItem.Index.ToString()); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the collection bound to the listview?

Comment: And do you have the System.Linq namespace among the usings?

Comment: No, I dont use Linq, I think I'm using an older .Net on my project so Linq doesn't work there... I think. I tried adding using System.Linq; but it gives error. So if this is possible without Linq I think that would be better.

Comment: @spunit yes but this only works if you use the mouse ... so be carefull ... Vinod's solution is much more safe to use

Comment: @spunit but i have no clue in which order the events are fired and if it's the last item clicked event is the one you last selected.. maybe you should try